# Thymeleaf + Spring parse HTML5 boolean tag

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble getting Thymeleaf to render my video. Sample html below:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>
```

I get:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "controls" associated with an element type "video" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

How can I get Thymeleaf to respect the `controls` attribute?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not saying this is a good idea, but could you just give it a useless value as a possible workaround (until you find the proper solution)? Something like `controls="controls"` or `controls="true"` or `controls=""`? Would at least satisfy XHTML syntax.

Comment: controls="controls" work properly.

Answer (score 2):

With spring-boot just set the "spring.thymeleaf.mode" property to LEGACYHTML5:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

Since Thymeleaf 2.0  (see [Generalized Template Modes](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#tmod)):

```
ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
// templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML5);   DEPRECATED!!
templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");              // OK for 2.0!
```